# Accessing DB2 through StarSQL - Efficiency. Output Parameters or Select Query

Tags: c#, db2, mainframe

I'm working on some code that queries an old DB2 database running on a nice old MainFrame. The Query has to be written in [StarSQL](http://www.starquest.com/Supportdocs/techStarSQL/browsesql.shtml) The goal of this is to drastically reduce the MIP's usage of the current query that is being passed in via Command.Text.

To those that do not know, you get charged (a LOT!) based on CPU Usage (MIP) on mainframes, thus you want things to run as efficiently as possible. You don't really want to say "Select * From TableA" and pass that as a CommandType.Text to the Database because it's going to need to compile that statement and then return the results. You'd need to save that as a procedure (which is already compiled) and strip out the * for the exact columns you want.

So, my question. I cannot answer this myself because our MainFrame guru is on vacation...

I have a procedure that returns ~30 columns. Would it be more efficient to return these through a Select query, or by returning them as output parameters. This is through a Stored Procedure.

I'm not worried about length of C# code, but efficiency on that blasted Mainframe.

I need to take in account things like:

```
SELECT PHNS.CLNT_INTERNL_KY as CLNT_INTRNL_KY
```

Uses extra CPU usage to apply that column name to that column, but would it be more efficient to save that as a output parameter using cursors?

If you would like any other information let me know.

Cheers,

(There "could" be a starSQL Tag on the tags, but alas I'm not 1500 points...)

Comment: Are you using ADO.NET to access the DB2?

Comment: I'm using the System.Data.Common namespace. It contains classes shared by the .NET Framework data providers. So yes.

Comment: I've never heard of this pricing scheme before, even though my job has dealt with multiple long-running processes (even ad-hoc, at multiple hours!).  This sounds like a micro-optimization type of detail - we're told to be aware of certain performance implications, but no more.  Also, your 'costs' will **not** be constant, as DB2 (and probably all RDBMS's) runs at least a portion of the optimizer for every statement run, and you _may_ not have control of when it completely re-optimizes your query...  You're likely best off just writing good SQL - anything too optimized may confuse people.

Comment: @X-Zero that's kind of what I'm thinking. Unfortunately the one query utilizes 90% of the CPU during it's compiling, and that was the first thing to change, now we're seeing if we can squeeze any more out of it.

Comment: I expect the only way to check the efficiency of the SP is to create it and run it (don't forget to run it in _different_ jobs, as some DB2 installations will cache things in the same job...).  I've never created a SP, so I can't give figures there.  Something else to try would be to create a view, then select from the view (might be somewhat more flexible); that should at least remove _most_ of the work needed for 'compilation' (although depending on what type of restrictions you give it, it _may_ re-optimize the query).

Comment: In DB2, views do not provide any compilation by themselves; the statement has to be part of a stored procedure or embedded SQL package in order to be precompiled.

The efficiency of a stored procedure (and also dynamic SQL) can be checked with DB2 EXPLAIN. There is no need to treat statements and procedures as black boxes that are only measured at runtime.

When DB2 caches the compiled access plan for a dynamic query, any job/application is eligible to re-use that access plan if it executes the exact same statement. Keep in mind that only the access plan is cached, not the results of the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many query APIs do not permit the use of stored procedures, but if you have that option, using a stored procedure can save some CPU time by parsing and optimizing the query once at compile time rather than during every execution. If not, you may still benefit from the caching that takes place for dynamic SQL statements. The access plans for dynamic statements are temporarily stored in the package cache, so if the same byte-for-byte identical statement (including parameter markers and literal values) is encountered soon enough, DB2 will reuse the access plan from the package cache instead of optimizing it from scratch all over again.

Using stored procedures can save a significant amount of compile time for statements that are run very frequently with different literal values. In cases where the input parameters are optional or can vary considerably (such as flexible searches), a stored procedure could produce an undesirable access plan at compile time because it doesn't know which parameters will be populated at runtime. In those situations, the stored procedure may need to re-optimize the query at runtime through a REOPT policy, but that approach obviously takes away the savings of precompilation.

I'd recommend using DB2's EXPLAIN facility to determine where the real costs are in your query workload (compilation vs. scanning vs. sorting). If a query scans a significant number of rows, the CPU costs of evaluating each row can quickly surpass the expense of optimizing a dynamic query. Queries that issue SELECT * often prevent the optimizer from exploiting an index that could satisfy the same query with fewer I/O operations. Filter and join predicates in the WHERE clause (or the lack of them) can also prevent the optimizer from selecting an index.

Comment: Thanks Fred. Another Optimization we found is that if you need 10 records returned, it's more efficient to do 10 small hits on the server, rather than hit it once and let it parse through which records to create, especially if you tell it to only select 1 record

Comment: All things being equal, I generally try to minimize the number of round-trips between the application and the database server. If executing ten separate statements turns out to run faster than a single query that returns ten rows, it's usually because of some inefficiency in the query. I'd be curious to see what EXPLAIN has to say about the cost of the single query vs. the smaller ones.

Comment: It comes when the system has to parse an the incoming stream of ID's to look at. If we say "Get us the records for ID: 5918, 1,423,2938,142, 523 the CPU usage to parse those values, and build the output for them actually is greater in total than sending those as seperate queries. Also, telling the Db2 system that we only want the first row stops it from loading additional logic methods which cuts down on CPU usage. This probably isn't an issue in modern Database systems (ie Oracle), but it is apparently on this one.

Comment: It's unlikely that parsing is the main cost difference between the two query patterns. What's more likely is that the list of values (which I'm guessing are being specified as an IN expression) is resulting in a range scan instead of a simple fetch that you're probably seeing when you ask for one row at a time. Asking for the first row only can help, but once again, I'd recommend looking at the EXPLAIN report for the query instead of speculating. As for modernity, DB2's cost-based query optimizer is plenty capable, but it relies heavily on fresh RUNSTATS and works best with straightforward SQL